# How to add a list of tuples (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm extremely new to Python (Usually use c++) and have to add a list of tuples. The tuples are paired in as (item, price). My function will take in a list of these tuples, and add them together. If one of the items doesn't exist in my tuples list, then my function will just return 0. I've never had to deal with tuples before, so i'm a bit lost on how to go about this. Also, how would I iterate through the list that my function takes in?

Comment: "add them together" how? Add their prices? Add their item names? Concatenate them into a list? What would you do in C++?

Comment: It would find if the item exists in my tuple list. Then add the price of it to a running total. In C++, I would have to know how long the list was, then iterate over and match the strings together. If a string didn't match, then return 0

Comment: "the item"? Aren't you given a list of items? Why would an item in the list, not be in the list?

Comment: really need to add some input and expected output

Comment: Because my list of items could be: ((apple, 2.0), (orange,3.00),(banana, 4.00)). But the person could request grapes, which wouldn't be in my tuple list. The orderList they're giving is (fruit, numberOfPounds)

Comment: So you actually have a list of (item, price) tuples and another list of items and you want to know how expensive those items are?

Comment: does the function take input from a user?

Comment: Yes it does. But the user could put in an item that doesn't exist in our original list of items

Comment: Your accepted answer treats the second arg as prices but your orderList has  numberOfPounds as the second parameter, the accepted  code will also crash on incorrect input so your questions makes no sense at all now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of a list of tuples, you should use a dictionary to store the prices.

```
def sum_prices(orderList, productPrices):
    sum = 0
    for (item, pounds) in orderList:
        if item not in productPrices:
            return 0
        sum += pounds * productPrices[item]
    return sum
```

This function can be used like:

```
prices = {"apple" : 1.50, "banana" : 3.80, "cranberry" : 9.99}
order = [("apple", 4), ("banana", 1)]
total = sum_prices(order, prices)
```

If you need the prices as a list of `(item, pricePerPound)` tuples, you can always get one by calling the `items()` function of the dictionary.

**Note:** Returning 0 if an order list contains invalid items is probably a bad idea since it cannot be distinguished from the return value for an empty list.  I'd rather return –1 or, even better, throw an exception.

Comment: Products will be a list of tuples (item, pounds) that is getting matched against a list of tuples (item, cost). So I have to take (item,pounds) and compare it to my list of (item,cost)